# How to share my Firefox extension set?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

When showing colleagues my Firefox setup a lot of them like the combination of extensions. All extensions look for their updates, so they kind of "know" where they came from.

Is there a way that I can render an HTML file that contains the links to the original install location of my extensions, so a colleague could install some or all of them themselves?

What is the right way to share extensions?

Answer (score 6):

One can also make an [add-on collection](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/editors_picks) (at Mozilla).

Comment: This is what collections are for indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Extension List Dumper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3746) add-on is just what you're looking for!

[image: Extension List Dumper screenshot]

I used the dump extension to create [this HTML list of the add-ons I use](http://www.jaredharley.com/jareds-addons.html). It's not super-pretty, but it includes links to the developer's websites (or whatever they specify in the add-on properties).

Once installed, all you have to do is click the "Dump List" button at the bottom of the add-on window.

Answer (score 2):

These days you should probably use AMO collections, as Nathaniel suggested, but I couldn't resist linking to an extension I wrote for this a long time ago: [InfoLister](http://mozilla.doslash.org/infolister/).

Answer (score 2):

[Silence of the Foxes](http://lifehacker.com/5355131/silence-of-the-foxes-creates-custom-firefox-installations) allows to to build a silent and custom Firefox installation.
You can add bookmarks, search extensions, plugins and extensions, and wrap it up into an installation, and the distribute it to your colleagues if you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ? [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109)

Comment: This will spit out your add-ons to .xpi and .jar files. If you want to actually share the files, this might work. However, I'm not sure if it preserves the settings you have for the add-ons or not.

Comment: You're killin me, cause I'm not sure anymore. I used it many times for backing up my ext's, and I don't remember setting them again afterwards. Let's say, I'm 80% sure it does preserve them.

Comment: Sorry. =) -----